# $_SESSION variable in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I try a query like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE `user`=$_SESSION['valid_user'] LIMIT 1");
```

it doesn't work. Why? I escaped the variable, then tried it without, and tried putting quotes around the variable. I know i can do:

```
$user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
```

but shouldn't it work without? Thanks.

THE ANSWER:

PHP can't recognize $_SESSION['valid_user'] due to the single quotes. So either 
use curly braces {} or take our the single quotes.

Thanks for helping me everyone.

Comment: thanks for fixing my code Quassnoi, my phone doesn't let me do that. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP can't recognise variables inside a string that have square brackets and so on, you have to wrap it in curly brackets to get it to recognise it.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE user={$_SESSION['valid_user']} LIMIT 1");
```

**However** - You should always escape any data going into a SQL query, try the example below.

```
$validUser = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['valid_user']);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE user='$validUser' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: +1 for the point about SQL injection. Session data can be safer (i.e. I can be reasonably certain that valid_user is either 0 or 1) but it's still good practice.

Comment: Thanks :). Yeah definitely, and escaping can help prevent bugs where the variable happens to contain quotes (in a legitimate, non malicious way)

Comment: First sentence is not true. It works fine without curly braces, if only you use the correct syntax: `"$_SESSION[valid_user]"` within double quotes.  (Curly braces are only required for *var expressions*.)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays/objects must be included in strings slightly differently:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE `user`={$_SESSION['valid_user']} LIMIT 1");
```

or, you can drop out of the string and concatenate it in:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE `user`=" . $_SESSION['valid_user'] . " LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: now it says- supplied argument is not a valid resource... wtf? my web host is gay ;(

Comment: I suspect your web host has no sexual orientation of any kind.

Comment: or simply do "SELECT .... $_SESSION[valid_user] ..." without the internal single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Same but with PDO and bound parameters

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE `user`=:user LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array(':user'=>$_SESSION['valid_user']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Note: you can't make LIMIT 1 into a bound parameter because LIMIT is not part of the standard sql and PDO has issues with it, so it has to be bound like this

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE `user`=:user LIMIT :limit');
$limit = 1;
$user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

or like this

```
$limit = 1;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE `user`=:user LIMIT '.(int)$limit);
$stmt->execute(array(':user'=>$_SESSION['valid_user']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

this is the way that I was taught to do it, so I wanted to point it out

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE `user`={$_SESSION['valid_user']} LIMIT 1");
```

also remember to put `session_start` on the top of the page

Answer (score -1):

your array is in this context just part of a string and nothing else. To mark an expression as what it is you have to embrace it curly ;-) works only with double quoted strings, though.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE user={$_SESSION['valid_user']} LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the string concatenation operator `'.'` before and after the variable.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE `user`=".$_SESSION['valid_user']." LIMIT 1");
```

Since you are using a double quoted string, you can also use `{}` around the variable instead of string concatenation:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE `user`={$_SESSION['valid_user']} LIMIT 1");
```

By the way, you probably should look into the `mysqli` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) library, and be using `mysqli::real_escape_string` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to ensure that any non-literal variable values are properly escaped.